# Generalized copy constructors

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance, polymorphism

Why do classes like `shared_ptr` have another template in their constructors?

For example:

```
template<class T> class shared_ptr {
public:
  template<class Y>
  explicit shared_ptr(Y * p);
```

I've been reading Scott Meyers's *Effective C++*, item 45, which says the idea behind it is to make polymorphism possible through them; that is, construct `shared_ptr<A>` from `shared_ptr<B>` if B is derived from A.

But isn't defining a constructor like

```
explicit shared_ptr(T * p);
```

enough? I mean, this code works just fine:

```
class C1 {
};

class C2 : public C1 {
};

template<typename T>
class A
{
public:
  A(T &a)
  {
    var1 = a;
  }

  T var1;
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  C2 c2;
  A<C1> inst1(c2);
}
```

So why do we need another template for constructor there?

Comment: What if the two types are not derived from each other using inheritance, but they are *convertible* between each other?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude if they are convertible to each other, won't 'my solution' work anyways? since the class will be instantiated for some type and regular conversion will happen, as this was one concrete class of some T?

Comment: Even if two objects of different types can be converted between each other, the types are still different. That would mean that the template parameter `T` would have to represent two different types, which is not possible.

Comment: can you please write example code? small, reproducible? because I think I didn't get it

Comment: `T` can actually be an incomplete type at the time of the constructor call, but `Y` must be a complete type (though how this can occur currently evades me).  Thus, in such a situation the non-template constructor would not work.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude It's the pointer types, not the pointee types that must be convertible.

Answer (score 13):

Without the template constructor, the following code would have undefined behavior:

```
#include <memory>

class Base {};
class Derived : public Base {};

int main() {
    std::shared_ptr<Base> ptr( new Derived );
}
```

If `shared_ptr` takes only a `Base*`, it is forced to eventually call `delete` on that `Base*` pointer.  But since `Base` does not have a virtual destructor and the pointer actually points at `Derived`, this is undefined behavior.

But in reality, the code above is well-formed.  The template constructor for `shared_ptr` takes a `Derived*` pointer and stores a custom deleter that calls `delete` on the original `Derived*` pointer, which is fine.

Comment: I think this is a good explanation of why it is necessary for `std::shared_ptr` but I think this pattern is common in other places in the standard library where there is no need for a deleter.

Comment: This is a rather marginal side effect of having custom deleters. They are a nice extra and not the motivating force behind shared_ptr (which is *sharing* the pointee).

Comment: @n.m.: The ability to have a `shared_ptr` to a subobject and a deleter managing lifetime of the complete object is a pretty powerful capability of `shared_ptr`.  Base subobjects are just a special case, the ability also covers member subobjects and even "owned" peer objects.

Comment: @BenVoigt this is an interesting functionality enabled by custom deleters but one needs a different constructor in order to use it.

Answer (score 1):

```
explicit shared_ptr(T * p);
```

If `shared_ptr` only had this constructor, it would defeat its entire purpose, which is to provide a reference-counted pointer.

The reference count (or rather a pointer thereto) is a part of `shared_ptr`. It should be updated every time a `shared_ptr` is created, destroyed, or copied. And this last part can only be achieved if `shared_ptr` is passed to the copying routine. Passing a bare pointer will create a `shared_ptr` with reference count of 1.

A reference-counted pointer is only shared when its reference count goes beyond 1. With your scheme it isn't clear how this is supposed to ever happen.

Some reference-counting functionality is provided by a normal (non-template) copy constructor. But not all of it.

For example,

```
 std::shared_ptr<Derived> d;
 std_shared_ptr<Base> b;
 ...
 b = d;
```

would fail to compile without the template "copy' constructor. We want shared poiters to provide the same polymorphic behaviour as normal pointers, so we want the above construction to Just Work. A template constructor provides that.

Comment: I think the question is why we have `template<typename Y> explicit shared_ptr(Y*);`, not why we have `shared_ptr(const shared_ptr&);` and `template<typename Y> shared_ptr(const shared_ptr<Y>&);`.

Comment: @aschepler I don't think the question is asked in full awareness of why `shared_ptr` needs even a normal copy constructor. I will add some explanation anyway.

Comment: @n.m. first of all thanks for response. but, isn't the idea behind those smart pointers to behave like normal pointers with some added functionality? (e.g. ref counting). the code you wrote, I think one of them should be 'd'

Comment: Yes it's a typo, fixed.

Comment: in code you wrote, using same template will do I think, thats what I'm asking: my code works, and it's exactly same situation that you wrote

Comment: No, it is not in the same situation. You need to be aware of two facts. One, there's more data in shared_ptr than just a pointer yo your object. Two, this additional data is needed to maintain the integrity of. *other* shared_ptr pointing to the same object. Your code has nothing similar to that.

Comment: @aschepler I would like to konw the reasoon of your question.

Comment: @Ds.Hale That wasn't a question. I don't really remember this well, but I think I just commented on a mismatch between the top question and a previous version of this answer, allowing n.m. to improve the answer.